# How to use specific d3 chart in pentaho

Tags: d3.js, pentaho, pentaho-cde, ccc, pentaho-ctools

I am using Pentaho CDE . I have a requirement to implement a d3 chart http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

i have installed the d3 component library. selected the d3 component from d3 components in the component panel.

how do i proceed coding. since this chart is taking json as input, but i need to pass sql data source.

could anyone guide me on this. I know this is quite a broad question, but i am stuck at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your data from a SQL table to the json the component requires.

If you're building a CDE dashboard, you should use CDA to query the database and return the result set.
Then in the D3 component postFetch function, execute the required transformations.

Comment: this is pretty old tutorial, but it might get you up and running with CDE: http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2011/06/creating-dashboards-with-cde/. There are other more up to date paid materials - google for CDE tutorial.

Comment: @PedroVale some other d3 chart in CDE tutorial?

Comment: No. If you want to use D3 in CDe, take a look at http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.pt/2014/05/d3-pentaho-component-gallery_17.html or check the new Visualization API component for CDF/CDE. If you download the TRUNK version of CDE there's a sample there that uses the Visualization API component to load a d3 chart.